# What if $b$ is an even integer in Weierstrass function?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

In [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) defined as $$f(x)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }a^{n}\cos(b^{n}\pi x),$$ we have the requirement that where $0<a<1$, $b$ is a positive odd integer, and $ab>1+{\frac {3}{2}}\pi$.

But what will happen if $b$ is an even integer? I know from [the proof](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Ebrent/files/104_weierstrass.pdf) that the oddness is used to reduce $(-1)^b$ to $-1$. However, I plotted the function when $b=8$, it seems still pathological (continuous&indifferentiable everywhere). I guess it has to do with asymptotic behavior.